# How should I count the number of launches of an application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, launching-application

- I have completed my application.
- Now when user launches my application **5 times**
- I want to display an alert message that "You have used more than 5 times better to go for next version".
- How should we count the number of launches and where do we call this alert view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use NSUserDefaults in applicationDidBecomeActive:.

```
NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger appLaunchAmounts = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"LaunchAmounts"];
        if (appLaunchAmounts == 5)
        {
           //Use AlertView


        }
        [userDefaults setInteger:appLaunchAmounts+1 forKey:@"LaunchAmounts"];
```

Comment: Just don't forget to check for nil - if it's nil you have to initialize it to 1 and save (synchronize). You also have to synchronize after each incrementation. And didFinishLaunching is not a good choice for newer iOS - where apps stay running in background and this method isn't called each time you launch. use didBecomeActive instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use method in your app delegate:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

to check how many times it was launched. Then you can simply use standard user defaults to read/write the value:

```
NSInteger i = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"numOfLCalls"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:i+1 forKey:@"numOfLCalls"];
```

After that check if "i" is greater then 5 and send a message to view controller so it will put alert message after its view loads or simply call the user defaults again where you want to display the alert and check value.

Comment: applicationDidBecomeActive would be better choice since it's called everytime user brings application up. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gets called only first time and when application is killed in background or removed from background processes by user. Othervise this is the way to go.

Comment: I agree with you, but it depends on what you want/need. The question was number of launches. If I understand the purpose correctly I would put it in didBecomeActive but also save the last date/time that number was increased and cap it to increase once a day or so max.

Comment: [Hemang Shah](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1179701/hemang-shah) [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/206093) "don't forget to synchronize your userdefault object."

Answer (score 1):

You could count the number of launches using [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Some more info: [Saving an int to nsuserdefaults](http://%20http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=217529)

You would implement your functionality in application delegate. Most probably in `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` method.

First you check if your `launchesSoFar` value is store. If not (if you get `nil`) you initialize it to 1 and don't forget to synchronize. If it exists already you increment it and again - sznchronize. If it's >=5 then do what you wan't to do.